# Optimizing a SELECT statement with ORDER BY by using indices

Tags: mysql

I have these queries:

1st query:

```
SELECT (..) FROM db WHERE A = const AND B > const AND C >= const ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT const
```

2nd query (different db):

```
SELECT (...) FROM db' WHERE A' = const ORDER BY X' DESC LIMIT const
```

Question about 1st query:
Is it sufficient to have a multiple row index (A, B, C) or do I need an additional single row index (B) (or a different one) because of the `ORDER BY`statement?

Question about 2nd query: Do I need a multiple row index (A', X') or two single row indices (A'), (X') to make us of them in this query?

Comment: That  really depends on the volumes and the rows resulting of your filter `WHERE A = const`. If this get back say, 1000 rows, you really don't need an index on `X'` to order afterwards, nor on `B` and `C` to help filter the results again. If it is millions of rows that's different. You should post your explain plans or there's nothing we can say.

Comment: This would be another question I would have asked but my assumption in this example is that I need the indexing and I want to know if MySQL needs (A,B,C) or (A,B), (C) indices when there is an `ORDER BY C` when there are filters for 1. A, B, C or 2. just A and B

Comment: But to answer your first question: My filters always reduce the result to a set of far below 1000 rows so I won't use B and C as indices. Thanks for your information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an important thing to know that MySQL will use at most one index (for  searching, filtering and ordering) per table and subquery (so basically per row in `explain`), so you can use only one index here.

For your first query, an index `(A,B)` will allow MySQL to do a range scan and use the order. If you use `(A,B,C)`, the column `C` cannot be used in the range condition (because `B` is already a range), but MySQL will save the time to read the actual tabledata to get the value for `C` to check the last condition. So `(A,B,C)` is in general the fastest choice here.

"In general", because you can of course have a data distribution where another index would be best: If you e.g. have only one or two rows that match `C >= const` and 10M+ rows with `A = const`, using an index on just `C` would be fastest. And if `C` is a very big column (e.g. `varchar(700)`), it could blow up the index and slow it down. But to estimate such exceptions would require deeper knowledge of your data.

For your second query, `(A', X')` will be the best choice. If you have the two indexes `(A')`, `(X')`, MySQL will in most cases  (unless `A'` is unique, but then you wouldn't need an `order by` anyway) use the index on `X'` and hope it will find matching rows for `A'` soon. This will sometimes be unexpectedly and painfully slow if you only have some rows that match `A' = const` (because it has to jump back and forth in the table (that is ordered by the primary key) in the order of `X'` to find rows that match the condition for `A'`).

You might get the same problem for your first query if you have the indexes `(A)` and `(B)` (but not `(A,B)` or `(A,B,C)`) there: MySQL will probably use `(B)` instead of `(A)` (but check the `explain` to make sure). Even if you just add one index now, this can e.g. happen when you add the index `(B)` to optimize a different query next week and forgot about this query, so I'd suggest to stick with (at least) `(A,B)`